# Pentaho 7.0 default date and time format

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am having  Pentaho 7.0 .

I am using JXL Excel Input  step to read into oracle DB 19.1

I have specified date format - DD/MMM/yyyy but its reading time also.

Can you specify what is default date / time format in pentaho 7.0.0-25.

Answer (score 0):

In the Calculator step one of the operations available is Remove time from a date A, you could use it to reset the date to 00:00:00.

Comment: thanks .but i want to know when sselect date but do not provide any format how pentaho behaves